# Android react-native WebView can't open google map

Tags: android, webview, react-native

It seems that using WebView to open google maps(i.e. https://maps.google.com) will cause a fatal error. The function 'onNavigationStateChange' will be called infinite times. I print the navState parameter to log and the following is the output:
[Log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmGlf.png)

Here is my code, which was modified from WebView Example.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    WebView
} = ReactNative;

var HEADER = '#3b5998';
var BGWASH = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)';
var DISABLED_WASH = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)';

var TEXT_INPUT_REF = 'urlInput';
var WEBVIEW_REF = 'webview';
var DEFAULT_URL = 'https://maps.google.com';

var WebViewExample = React.createClass({

                                       getInitialState: function() {
                                       return {
                                       url: DEFAULT_URL,
                                       status: 'No Page Loaded',
                                       backButtonEnabled: false,
                                       forwardButtonEnabled: false,
                                       loading: true,
                                       scalesPageToFit: true,
                                       };
                                       },

                                       inputText: '',

                                       handleTextInputChange: function(event) {
                                       var url = event.nativeEvent.text;
                                       if (!/^[a-zA-Z-_]+:/.test(url)) {
                                       url = 'http://' + url;
                                       }
                                       this.inputText = url;
                                       },

                                       render: function() {
                                       this.inputText = this.state.url;

                                       return (
                                               <View style={[styles.container]}>
                                               <View style={[styles.addressBarRow]}>
                                               <TouchableOpacity
                                               onPress={this.goBack}
                                               style={this.state.backButtonEnabled ? styles.navButton : styles.disabledButton}>
                                               <Text>
                                               {'<'}
                                               </Text>
                                               </TouchableOpacity>
                                               <TouchableOpacity
                                               onPress={this.goForward}
                                               style={this.state.forwardButtonEnabled ? styles.navButton : styles.disabledButton}>
                                               <Text>
                                               {'>'}
                                               </Text>
                                               </TouchableOpacity>
                                               <TextInput
                                               ref={TEXT_INPUT_REF}
                                               autoCapitalize="none"
                                               defaultValue={this.state.url}
                                               onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmitEditing}
                                               onChange={this.handleTextInputChange}
                                               clearButtonMode="while-editing"
                                               style={styles.addressBarTextInput}
                                               />
                                               <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pressGoButton}>
                                               <View style={styles.goButton}>
                                               <Text>
                                               Go!
                                               </Text>
                                               </View>
                                               </TouchableOpacity>
                                               </View>
                                               <WebView
                                               ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
                                               automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                                               style={styles.webView}
                                               source={{uri: this.state.url}}
                                               javaScriptEnabled={true}
                                               domStorageEnabled={true}
                                               decelerationRate="normal"
                                               onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
                                               onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
                                               startInLoadingState={true}
                                               scalesPageToFit={this.state.scalesPageToFit}
                                               />
                                               <View style={styles.statusBar}>
                                               <Text style={styles.statusBarText}>{this.state.status}</Text>
                                               </View>
                                               </View>
                                               );
                                       },

                                       goBack: function() {
                                       this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goBack();
                                       },

                                       goForward: function() {
                                       this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].goForward();
                                       },

                                       reload: function() {
                                       this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].reload();
                                       },

                                       onShouldStartLoadWithRequest: function(event) {
                                       // Implement any custom loading logic here, don't forget to return!
                                       return true;
                                       },

                                       onNavigationStateChange: function(navState) {
                                       console.log(navState);
                                       this.setState({
                                                     backButtonEnabled: navState.canGoBack,
                                                     forwardButtonEnabled: navState.canGoForward,
                                                     url: navState.url,
                                                     status: navState.title,
                                                     loading: navState.loading,
                                                     scalesPageToFit: true
                                                     });
                                       },

                                       onSubmitEditing: function(event) {
                                       this.pressGoButton();
                                       },

                                       pressGoButton: function() {
                                       var url = this.inputText.toLowerCase();
                                       if (url === this.state.url) {
                                       this.reload();
                                       } else {
                                       this.setState({
                                                     url: url,
                                                     });
                                       }
                                       // dismiss keyboard
                                       this.refs[TEXT_INPUT_REF].blur();
                                       },

                                       });

var Button = React.createClass({
                               _handlePress: function() {
                               if (this.props.enabled !== false && this.props.onPress) {
                               this.props.onPress();
                               }
                               },
                               render: function() {
                               return (
                                       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._handlePress}>
                                       <View style={[styles.button, this.props.enabled ? {} : styles.buttonDisabled]}>
                                       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.text}</Text>
                                       </View>
                                       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                       );
                               }
                               });

var ScaledWebView = React.createClass({

                                      getInitialState: function() {
                                      return {
                                      scalingEnabled: true,
                                      }
                                      },

                                      render: function() {
                                      return (
                                              <View>
                                              <WebView
                                              style={{
                                              backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                                              height: 200,
                                              }}
                                              source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/'}}
                                              scalesPageToFit={this.state.scalingEnabled}
                                              />
                                              <View style={styles.buttons}>
                                              { this.state.scalingEnabled ?
                                              <Button
                                              text="Scaling:ON"
                                              enabled={true}
                                              onPress={() => this.setState({scalingEnabled: false})}
                                              /> :
                                              <Button
                                              text="Scaling:OFF"
                                              enabled={true}
                                              onPress={() => this.setState({scalingEnabled: true})}
                                              /> }
                                              </View>
                                              </View>
                                              );
                                      },
                                      })

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
                               container: {
                               flex: 1,
                               backgroundColor: HEADER,
                               },
                               addressBarRow: {
                               flexDirection: 'row',
                               padding: 8,
                               },
                               webView: {
                               backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                               height: 350,
                               },
                               addressBarTextInput: {
                               backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                               borderColor: 'transparent',
                               borderRadius: 3,
                               borderWidth: 1,
                               height: 24,
                               paddingLeft: 10,
                               paddingTop: 3,
                               paddingBottom: 3,
                               flex: 1,
                               fontSize: 14,
                               },
                               navButton: {
                               width: 20,
                               padding: 3,
                               marginRight: 3,
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               justifyContent: 'center',
                               backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                               borderColor: 'transparent',
                               borderRadius: 3,
                               },
                               disabledButton: {
                               width: 20,
                               padding: 3,
                               marginRight: 3,
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               justifyContent: 'center',
                               backgroundColor: DISABLED_WASH,
                               borderColor: 'transparent',
                               borderRadius: 3,
                               },
                               goButton: {
                               height: 24,
                               padding: 3,
                               marginLeft: 8,
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                               borderColor: 'transparent',
                               borderRadius: 3,
                               alignSelf: 'stretch',
                               },
                               statusBar: {
                               flexDirection: 'row',
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               paddingLeft: 5,
                               height: 22,
                               },
                               statusBarText: {
                               color: 'white',
                               fontSize: 13,
                               },
                               spinner: {
                               width: 20,
                               marginRight: 6,
                               },
                               buttons: {
                               flexDirection: 'row',
                               height: 30,
                               backgroundColor: 'black',
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               justifyContent: 'space-between',
                               },
                               button: {
                               flex: 0.5,
                               width: 0,
                               margin: 5,
                               borderColor: 'gray',
                               borderWidth: 1,
                               backgroundColor: 'gray',
                               },
                               });

const HTML = `
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Static World</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=no">
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font: 62.5% arial, sans-serif;
background: #ccc;
}
h1 {
padding: 45px;
margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
color: #33f;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Static World</h1>
</body>
</html>
`;

exports.displayName = (undefined: ?string);
exports.title = '<WebView>';
exports.description = 'Base component to display web content';
exports.examples = [
                    {
                    title: 'Simple Browser',
                    render(): ReactElement<any> { return <WebViewExample />; }
                    },
                    {
                    title: 'Scale Page to Fit',
                    render(): ReactElement<any> { return <ScaledWebView/>; }
                    },
                    {
                    title: 'Bundled HTML',
                    render(): ReactElement<any> {
                    return (
                            <WebView
                            style={{
                            backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                            height: 100,
                            }}
                            source={require('./helloworld.html')}
                            scalesPageToFit={true}
                            />
                            );
                    }
                    },
                    {
                    title: 'Static HTML',
                    render(): ReactElement<any> {
                    return (
                            <WebView
                            style={{
                            backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                            height: 100,
                            }}
                            source={{html: HTML}}
                            scalesPageToFit={true}
                            />
                            );
                    }
                    },
                    {
                    title: 'POST Test',
                    render(): ReactElement<any> {
                    return (
                            <WebView
                            style={{
                            backgroundColor: BGWASH,
                            height: 100,
                            }}
                            source={{
                            uri: 'http://www.posttestserver.com/post.php',
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: 'foo=bar&bar=foo'
                            }}
                            scalesPageToFit={false}
                            />
                            );
                    }
                    }
                    ];

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => WebViewExample);
```

If anyone can help me fix this problem, I would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you fix it, but here is an option if you want :
       -Using `<Mapview>` and react-native-maps : [look here](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I still can't fix it. I think it might be the bug of WebView when running on Android. If you try the following steps, you will also get the same problem. 1, use WebView to open http://amazon.com. 2, click 'Sign In' button.